# Is there a way to set the vlines below/under the candlesticks on plot? (mplfinance)

Tags: python, finance, mplfinance

I am currently using vlines to shadow in afterhours/premarket trading. However, the candlesticks are under the vlines and as such they become harder to read if I increase the alpha kwarg. Is there a way to put the vlines under the candlesticks as opposed to above them?
Using the mplfinance lib.

[image: figure]

PS: the vlines are also ever so slighly off the top of the plot, is there a way for them to go all the way up to the top edge?

```
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df,
                           type='candle',
                           volume=True,
                           ylabel='',
                           ylabel_lower='\n<thousands>',
                           returnfig=True,
                           style=style,
                           figratio=(21, 9),
                           warn_too_much_data=970,
                           addplot=vwap,
                           hlines=dict(hlines=previousCloseLine(), colors='white', linestyle='dashed'),
                           vlines=dict(vlines=df.between_time('16:00', '09:30').index.tolist(), colors='#323538', linewidths=1, alpha=0.5),
                           datetime_format='%H:%M',
                           tight_layout=True
                           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question (vlines below candlesticks), sounds like you are asking about [**`zorder`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html).  If so, mplfinance presently does not give you direct access to zorder.  There is [an enhancement request for it](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/311) that unfortunely got pushed onto the back-burner in favor of some other enhancements.
There may be a work-around using `returnfig=True` but I'm not sure yet if that can work (would have to run some experiments to see if zorder can be modified this way).

*In the meantime*, given what you are trying to do (shade an area of the plot) you might [**try mplfinance's `fill_between` feature**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/fill_between.ipynb).  Don't know if that will have the same zorder issue or not, but it is worth a try.

---

Regarding your second question (about vlines not quite reaching the top of the plot), not sure what's causing that, or whether it is inherent to mplfinance and/or to matplotlib, possibly only in response to certain data.

One possible workaround, in the meantime, may be to set the `ylim=(ymin,ymax)` kwarg to set ymin and ymax manually (instead of letting mplfinance determine them automatically).  It may be worth [adding an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/new/choose) to the mplfinance page, including all the data and code necessary to reproduce the issue.  It doesn't seem to me that vlines should stop short of the top like that.